# How to update checkout order totals?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, checkout, onepage-checkout, theme

I just need some direction, please… I feel lost.

Basically I'm using Magento 1.7 & I’m working on a module that gives a customer an option to add gift wrapping during the onepage checkout process.  I’m up to the point where I need to change the checkout total to reflect the change in price (and of course I would like to do this the right way.)

Looking at the frontend, I want to change this (under Order Review):

```
Subtotal $54.00
Shipping & Handling (Flat Rate - Fixed) $20.00
Grand Total $74.00
```

To this:

```
Subtotal $54.00
Gift Wrap $5.00
Shipping & Handling (Flat Rate - Fixed) $20.00
Grand Total $79.00
```

Comment: any one please help me to sort out this issue....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link will hopefully guide into the right direction. It explains how to create a custom total:
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total

Comment: thanks tim for this helpful link. my problem is solve :)

Comment: In the answer link, not mention where to save files, what should the file's name etc. Since I am new in magento please someone say (or suggest)  more detailed tutorial which says where to save page(page location ), page name etc for the same topic...thanks.